# Is there any way how to detect if an image is blurry in React Native?

Tags: react-native, image-processing

Is there any way how to detect if an image is blurry in React Native?
I need to check if a photo is blurry before sending it to the Server Api and I couldn't found any library that could help me

Answer (score 1):

Found this [tutorial](https://brainhub.eu/blog/opencv-react-native-image-processing/).
hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I too need the same library to verify the image before sending it to the backend. There is other way, which we can send to backend API and verify it but there is no library to do it in frontend.